# variables in scope firebase functions - async loop

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I have the following simple loop, that I use many times. I loop through a set of data, and need to do an async call (Firebase in this case) to fetch more details about a specific key.

When I run the async function, I often need the current key. But, since `admin.database` is async the loop just goes on. Often, before it reaches `console.log`, `currentItem` is already changed to the next item in the loop.

I think this is a common issue, but what would be the best way to get the proper value in the `admin.database()` functions scope?

```
function test() {

   const items = ["a", "b", "c"];
   for (var i=0; i< items.length; i++) {

     ...do stuff
     var currentItem = items[i];
     admin.database().ref("/different/items/"+currentItem).once("value").then(arraySnap => {
             console.log(currentItem)
     })    
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you not read the parent of the items and then loop through the children and extract the items you want?

Comment: In many cases they are not connected as parent  / child.